# What are these shell escape characters?

Tags: shell, emacs, coffeescript

I'm trying out the coffee script repl inside Emacs (under ArchLinux) and I'm seeing these escape characters surrounding the prompt:

```
[1Gcoffee> [0K[9G
```

These shouldn't be colors as I already enabled the `ansi-color-for-comint-mode`. So does anyone recognize these?

P.S.: Funny thing is I don't have this issue under my Emacs+Cygwin setup!

Comment: The root cause as I understand it is Emacs' terminal emulation being limited to vt100 or at least lacking some extensions. I just asked this question expanding its support http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/extended-cursor-movement-in-terminal-emulator-cha-and-others

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know where they're coming from (something to do with your shell prompt, obviously, but it's hard to say more than that).

I read them as:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[1G` - Move to column 1 (Cursor Character Absolute)
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[0K` - Erase to right
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[9G` - Move to column 9

It looks like an attempt by the shell to ensure that the prompt is at the far left of an empty line. Not sure what shell you have, but [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) does something similar when the `PROMPT_SP` option is enabled. I don't think it uses the above sequences, though.

Many, *many*, control sequences can be found [here](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html). Note that the sequence "<kbd>ESC</kbd>`[`" is interpreted as a "Control Sequence Introducer" (CSI) and is shown as that on that page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find the culprit with this information at hand. I'm using bash by the way.

Comment: Nice to have an explanation of what these codes mean, but did the OP ever find an actual solution? Encountering the same problem myself.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by adding

```
export NODE_NO_READLINE=1
```

to my `.bashrc` file.

So, the characters appear to have come from the CoffeeScript REPL's use of Readline. Perhaps the reason you didn't have the issue in Cygwin was because Readline wasn't available there.

Comment: Thanks for this answer (and for the question)! I just had the same problem and a search landed me here. I might never have guessed Node, since [Ubuntu built CoffeeScript](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/coffeescript-in-ubuntu-1110.html), not me.